# Set anonymous type to null at creation

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, anonymous-types

I tried creating an anonymous type and setting it to `null` at creation time. However, this, in my opinion, obvious method doesn't work

```
new {MyClass Value, int Total} min = null; //will not work
```

The workaround I stumbled on which works uses [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) to achieve the desired objective.

```
var min = Enumerable.Repeat(new {Value = new MyClass(), Total = 0}, 0)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
```

How I think it works is by creating a 0-size collection of the anonymous type and then returning the first item (which is null) to the desired variable.

What I'd like to know is, is there any **cleaner** *and possibly* **better** way besides the one I'm using to set the value of an anonymous type to `null` at the time of creation?

Comment: `First()` will throw an exception if there is no item that can be returned. You should be using `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Having said that, you probably shouldn't do that at all. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: When you're going to this much trouble.. why not just wrap it into an actual class?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Sorry. My bad. It's actually `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

this works all right if you want to assign null to anonymous types

```
var min = new { Value = new MyClass(), Total = 0 }
min = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fully understand your needs and I encounter this a few times already where I do want to have a local but strong-typed (anonymous type though) variable.

But unfortunately i don't think there is really any neat way to do it - another option is to use Enumerable.Range(0,0).Select(...).FirstOrDefault(), very similar to your Repeater.

Now whenever I face this situation, i would try Tuple instead:

```
Tuple<int, string, string> myVariable = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
var min = new { Value = (object)null };
```

But I fail to really understand the point of a line of code like that.

Comment: -1: This is something else. He basically wants `min` to be `null`. Not one of its properties.